# Instantiate scala type with factory as functional literal

Tags: scala

Given the following answer to a question posted here previously, how would I change the fac function to take a constructor argument?

```
class BalanceActor[T <: Actor](val fac: () => T) extends Actor {
  val workers: Int = 10

  private lazy val actors = new Array[T](workers)

  override def start() = {
    for (i <- 0 to (workers - 1)) {
      actors(i) = fac() //use the factory method to instantiate a T
      actors(i).start
    }
    super.start()
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious about the down-vote on this question. Could whoever did it explain?

Answer (score 5):

For a `String` argument:

`class BalanceActor[T <: Actor](val fac: String => T) extends Actor ...`

For an `A` argument:

`class BalanceActor[A, T <: Actor](val fac: A => T) extends Actor ...`